# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '$......' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so i have a code like this , i used it for a component

```html
<p><input id="note" ></p>
<div><span class="dialog"></span></div>

<script>
let $mathElement = $('.dialog');
let dialSpan = $mathElement[0];
let noteSpan = document.getElementById('note');

try {
    // a function to render
 render(noteSpan.value, dialSpan);
}
catch(e) { 
 
}

</script>
```

and there's also a function to allow me to hide and show this component.
but the problem is after i hide and reopen it there is a eror that said "$element" has already  been declared ,
can you guys tell me how to avoid this error

the error :

[image]

Comment: What does `render` do? I suspect you're reloading the same script into your page again and since you're using global variables, you cannot redefine any `let` or `const` ones. You could solve this by using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) though you may not actually want to reload your script

Answer (score -1):

**You can't redeclare/override a `let` variable.**

You may want to use some `var` here.

```
 var $mathElement = $('.dialog');
    var dialSpan = $mathElement[0];
    let noteSpan = document.getElementById('note');
```

Comment: This is no the issue here, the above code will still not run